# How to enable cross origin resource sharing (CORS) in Cesium Sandcastle for Geoserver WMS Get request

Tags: geoserver, sandcastle, cesiumjs

I am trying fist to test and practice in cesium sandcatle with my data on localhost:8080 geoserver.

[This picture will explane everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g5oi.png)

Also, i want to ask, "how to get a list of GeoServer layers loaded into the Cesium BaseLayerPicker" 
From example http://localhost:8080/geoserver/masterrad/wfs?request=GetCapabilities give XML file, with possible layers in workspaces 'masterrad'. How to extract names from that XML and put in BaseLayerPicker

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be two unrelated questions, but I'll try to answer both.

You can enable CORS in Geoserver using the CORS Filter plugin:
http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html

As for your second question, Cesium does not have built-in support for querying WFS GetCapabilities, but TerriaJS does:
https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs

TerriaJS is an open-source library built on top of Cesium that was originally developed for Australia's NationalMap and has since been used for a lot of other projects.  TerriaJS also has a fallback to Leaflet for systems that can't run Cesium.  Once you have CORS working on your server, visit [nationalmap.gov.au](http://nationalmap.gov.au) (a site running TerriaJS), click Add Data, enter your WFS URL, and you should see all of the server's layers appear at the bottom of the Data Catalogue.

Comment: thanks for answer. But, In link that you gave me for CORS, do i need to change something in <filter></filter> tag-s, or just copy to my web.xml of my geoservers? thanks.

Comment: You need to add both the <filter> and <filter-mapping> sections to your web.xml, but you shouldn't need to make any changes to the content.  Just copy/paste what it says in step 2 of the installation instructions.

Comment: @kring i am getting this error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sattawat/wms?BBOX=-1...' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. DO you know how can i disable this?